# On factorization algorithms for $\mathcal{O}[x]$

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, ac.commutative-algebra, computational-number-theory, factorization

We know that $\mathsf{LLL}$ algorithm provides factorization procedure that runs in poly time for polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$ that are primitive.

What other rings $\mathcal{O}$ can we use instead of $\Bbb Z$ in $\mathsf{LLL}$ procedure?

Is there a class of rings $\mathcal{O}$ that cannot be used?